# Crack the code: L0EJAU

Tags: word

I have a code for you:

> L0EJAU

Amazon's biggest rival was the one who made this. What is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting, this is my answer

> Searching "Amazon's biggest rival" bring google at the top of the result, searching "L0EJAU" bring random page, but there is one that makes me interested, bit.ly/L0ejAU, it takes me to korean website (I think), but changing bit.ly with goo.gl take me to this riddle, so my answer, that (L0EJAU) is google short url (http://goo.gl/L0EJAU) code that point to this question.